# Passing two parameter functions into apply

Tags: r

Say I have a function called

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {median(x,y)} # obviously the actual function is 
                                     # something more complicated
```

Now lets say in a certain use, the y parameter is constant, (say `c(1,2,3,4,5)`). Is there any way I can pass this into apply without wrapping it in another function?
i.e.

instead of

```
apply(mydf, 2, function(x) myfun(x, c(1,2,3,4,5)))
```

to pass something like

```
apply(mydf, 2, myfun(,(c(1,2,3,4,5))))
```

This is purely cosmetic and I know it won't make much difference to the running time. I just want to know if an option like this is possible because wrapping my function in a function each time seems inefficient

Comment: Optional arguments can be passed to FUN via the `...` in apply as documented in the help for `?apply`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
apply(mydf, 2, myfun, y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Remains untested as I can't access R right now.